# prove based on functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Prove that for all $f,g\in \Bbb N \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ there exist $h\in \Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb N$ bijection so : $$f = g\circ h  \rightarrow f=g$$ My attempt was to assume that for all $f,g\in \Bbb N \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ there exist $h\in \Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb N$ bijection so : $f = g\circ h  \land f\neq g$ and try to get a contradiction without any succed.

Answer (score 1):

Not always true:

$f(1)=0,\, f(2)=1,\, f(n)=1\, (n\ge3)$.

$g(1)=1,\, g(2)=0,\, g(n)=1\, (n\ge3)$.

$h(1)=2,\, h(2)=1,\,h(n)=n\, (n\ge3)$.

---

$g(h(1))=g(2)=0=f(1)$.

$g(h(2))=g(1)=1=f(2)$.

If $n\ge3$, $g(h(n))=g(n)=1=f(n)$.